# Java Game: Using minimax or similar algorithm for AI battles

Tags: java, game-design, algorithm

**Game Info:**

- Type: grid based ship game; where ships are one-directional (meaning they can only use the allowed moves in the direction it is facing)
- Allowed Directions: NORTH,SOUTH,WEST,EAST
- Allowed Moves: FORWARD, LEFT, RIGHT (LEFT and RIGHT moves at diagonals)
- Allowed Total Moves per Turn: 4 (3 for bigger ships) // (all ships play their moves in the same turn)
- Players allowed: 2+ (as many as server can hold)
- Shooting: ships can shoot only from the left or right side of ship (player ships will have to be on the same X position or same Y position to hit each other (cannonballs go a max of 4 tiles)).

---

Example video:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FY1JuNkYFLU&t=155s

---

With the provided information I would like to create a battling algorithm for when player ships get close to AI; where AI will battle with player.

**Algorithm plan:**

1. Get players current position and facing on board
2. Run simulation on every possible moves for player (LEFT,RIGHT,FORWARD move for each of the 4 slots) and check which route AI has most chance of damaging ship
3. Have AI use route where it causes most damage.

I was thinking of some type of minmax algorithm; is there a better algorithm I could use? Also; could someone provide some sort of implementation so I know how to set it up, as I don't have experience with different types of algorithms.

```
public class DFS {
    private ServerContext context;
    public Hashtable<Position, MoveState> stateList;
    
    public DFS(ServerContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    public void search(Player player) {
        Position playerPosition = player.copy();
        List<MoveState> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
        stateList = new Hashtable<Position, MoveState>();
        MoveState currentState = new MoveState(playerPosition, player.getFace(), MoveType.NONE, 0);
        Stack<MoveState> stack = new  Stack<MoveState>();
        stack.add(currentState);
        currentState.visited = true;
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            MoveState state = stack.pop();
            if(state.position.getX() < 0 || state.position.getY() < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            stateList.put(state.position, state);
            if(state.time < 4) {
                int x = state.position.getX();
                int y = state.position.getY();
                switch (state.face) {
                    case NORTH:
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y), VesselFace.NORTH, MoveType.NONE,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y+1), VesselFace.NORTH, MoveType.FORWARD,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x-1,y+1), VesselFace.WEST, MoveType.LEFT, state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x+1,y+1), VesselFace.EAST, MoveType.RIGHT,state.time + 1));
                        break;
                    case EAST:
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y), VesselFace.EAST, MoveType.NONE,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x+1,y), VesselFace.EAST, MoveType.FORWARD,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x+1,y+1), VesselFace.NORTH, MoveType.LEFT,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x+1,y-1), VesselFace.SOUTH, MoveType.RIGHT,state.time + 1));
                        break;
                    case SOUTH:
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y), VesselFace.SOUTH, MoveType.NONE,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y-1), VesselFace.SOUTH, MoveType.FORWARD,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x-1,y-1), VesselFace.WEST, MoveType.RIGHT,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x+1,y+1), VesselFace.EAST, MoveType.LEFT,state.time + 1));
                        break;
                    case WEST:
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x,y), VesselFace.WEST, MoveType.NONE,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x-1,y), VesselFace.WEST, MoveType.FORWARD,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x-1,y+1), VesselFace.NORTH, MoveType.RIGHT,state.time + 1));
                        neighbors.add(new MoveState(new Position(x-1,y-1), VesselFace.SOUTH, MoveType.LEFT,state.time + 1));
                        break;
                }
            }
            for(MoveState neighborState : neighbors) {
                if(neighborState != null ) {
                    if(stateList.values().contains(neighborState)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    int at = context.getMap().getTile(neighborState.position.getX(), neighborState.position.getY());
                    if(at == 1 || at == 2) continue; // ignore rocks
                    if(context.getMap().isWind(at)){ // special action tiles
                        neighborState.position = context.getMap().getNextActionTilePositionForTile(neighborState.position, at);
                    }
                    if(context.getMap().isWhirlpool(at)) {
                        neighborState.position = context.getMap().getFinalActionTilePosition(at, neighborState.position, 0);
                        neighborState.face = neighborState.face.getNext();
                    }
                    if(!neighborState.visited)
                    {
                        stack.add(neighborState);
                        neighborState.visited = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MoveState {
    public Position position;
    public VesselFace face;
    public MoveType move;
    public int time;
    public boolean visited = false;

    public MoveState(Position position, VesselFace face, MoveType move, int time) {
        this.position = position;
        this.face = face;
        this.move = move;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked lots of questions recently that really seem to be about the same root issue: "How do I write an AI for Puzzle Pirates?" - Why not ask about this root issue explicitly? [This helps you avoid the X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/), which can burn out the experts who have been trying to help you through the past incarnations of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118325/discussion-between-dre-and-dmgregory).